# EditText cannot get focus back after set Focusable to false

Tags: java, android-edittext

I set `Focusable` of my `EditText` to `false` and then set it back to `true`. But it cannot get the focus back.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                if (et.isFocusable()){
                    et.setFocusable(false);
                } else {
                    et.setFocusable(true);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should reques focus again:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if (et.isFocusable()){
     et.setFocusable(false);
 }else {
     et.setFocusable(true);
     et.requestFocus();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a component is not focusable, the system assigns the focus to the next focusable component as a side effect. Making the component focusable again does not undo that side effect, so you have to make it happen.

Ensure you call the component's [requestFocus()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus()) method.